# Get a record with its realtionship as an array

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-orm

I have a model class with one-to-many relation.

```
class Budget extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('budgets');

        $this->hasMany('id', BudgetItem::class, 'budget_id');
    }
}

class BudgetItem extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSource('budget_items');

        $this->belongsTo('budget_id', Budget::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

So, one budget record has many budget_items. I want to fetch a budget by its id with all related items so I build a query:

```
$query = $modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->addFrom(Budget::class, 'b')
    ->leftJoin(BudgetItem::class, 'b.id = bi.budget_id', 'bi')
    ->columns('b.*, bi.*')
    ->where('b.id = :id:', ['id' => 1])
    ->getQuery();

$result = $query->execute();
```

But a result looks pretty odd for me.

```
{
    b: {
        id: "1"
    },
    bi: {
        id: "9",
        budget_id: "1",
        amount: "23500"
    }
},
{
    b: {
        id: "1"
    },
    bi: {
        id: "10",
        budget_id: "1",
        amount: "116500"
    }
}
```

Whereas I'm expecting a resultset that will look something like this:

```
{
    b: {
        id: "1"
        bi: [
            {
                id: "9",
                budget_id: "1",
                amount: "23500"
            }, {
                id: "10",
                budget_id: "1",
                amount: "116500"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get only one a budget object with an array of two items?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are not using the model relations, but query builder with normal left join. This will always return multiple rows.

If you really want only 1 budget with all his budget_items you can use the relations that you defined above.

```
$budget = Budget::findFirst(22);
$budget->id; // id of your Budget table and other columns
$budget->budget_items; // This will contain array of all your budget_items relation
```

Comment: In that case there are gonna be two request. One for a budget and one for its items.

So, there is no way to use phql or query builder for getting record and its relations as a single array?

Comment: You can not achieve this with query only. If you want to use the QueryBuilder way I would create a helper function which iterates over the results and transforms them in the way you requested.